# MySql Query Sample

Tags: mysql

I used this query and I think mysql server crushed down or something. can't reach now. is this a coincidence or my query is so bad? If its bad how can I fix it

working on 400.000 rows 2 tables one is scorelisting and other is users

```
SELECT a.* 
from 
(
    SELECT @curRank := @curRank +1 AS ROW , s.UserId,
       s.AverageScore As Score, u.UserName 
    FROM  scorelisting s, (SELECT @curRank :=0) r, Users u 
    where u.UserId=s.UserId 
    order by AverageScore desc
) a 
where UserId = 95890
```

Comment: Impossible to say without further information.  Do you have access to the host machine?  Is it still responsive?  Is the `mysqld` process still running?  How many records are there in your `scorelisting` and `Users` tables?  Do you have indexes on `Users.UserId` and `(scorelisting.UserId, scorelisting.AverageScore)`?

Comment: Do you have 400.000 users? It would seem so if you got 400.000 avarage scores. That's really a lot man. If you've got so many users, maybe you shouldn't calculate the rank in real time, but let a job recalculate the rank for all users and store it in your AvarageScore table. You can update the ranking once every hour or so.

Comment: @eggyal as I said 400.000 rows both tables. I don't have  access to the machine I use browser to connect mysql servers but now I can't open even server list(which is start screen for my panel) I don't have Indexes for now coz I am trying to equalize mssql tables with mysql tables(which is out of topic I believe)

Comment: @GolezTrol so you are saying my query is so bad I should do it once a hour but one time even made it crush, so not sure It will solve the problem??

Comment: If there are 400,000 records in each of the tables (your question doesn't say), then the materialised table `a` will have 400,000^2 = 160 billion records that must each be inspected for satisfaction of the filter criterion, after which a `filesort` (combination of quicksort and mergesort, therefore **Ω(*n* log *n*)**) must be performed.  So, in answer to "*is my query so bad?*" I'd hazard a guess that yes, it is.  Build appropriate indexes before attempting anything like this!!

Comment: @eggyal I am waiting mysql server to comeback to try samequery with indexes. to make it clear, by the indexes mean primary key right? I am gonna make UserId column's primary key. then try again?

Comment: @MertMermi: A primary key is one type of index, but not all indexes are primary keys.  Try reading the manual chapter on [Optimization and Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/optimization-indexes.html), then come back here with specific questions if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: @eggyal okey thank you to showing the path. Can't check your comment? is That ok? I am gonna study about indexes then try again If I can sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm over-simplifying this, but... IF you are looking for where a specific user is within a rank of others, I would find out what that person's "averageScore" is, then get a COUNT(*) of all records with an average BETTER than the one you want, and then get that person's name...  Make sense?  Then try the following.

**[REVISED AND TESTED -- SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78ee9/1)**
The sample on SQLFiddle has 6 entries for users a-f and averageScores of 10-60 respectively.  The query picks user 3 (avgScore) and thus has 3 (d, e and f) have higher averages (40, 50, 60) which puts user 'c' (id 3) in 4th place.

```
SELECT 
      u.UserName,
      PreQuery.AverageHigherThanYou +1 as UserRank
   from
      users u,
      ( select
              COUNT(*) as AverageHigherThanYou
           from 
              scoreListing s,
              ( select @MyAvg := s2.AverageScore
                   from scoreListing s2 
                   where s2.UserID = 95890 ) sqlvars
            where
               s.AverageScore > @MyAvg ) PreQuery
    where
       u.userid = 95890
```

The "PreQuery" just gets a count of all those LESS than the static-joined to scoreListing for your specific user and puts into a single column value.

Then a comma Users table (old ANSI, no join criteria) will always return the one record... Then, apply the WHERE clause only on the USER table for the one person to get their name info.

Now, if you wanted how many were Higher, Same or Lower average, you could adjust the query something like

```
  ( SELECT 
          sum( if( s.averageScore < s2.averageScore, 1, 0 )) as LowerAverageThanYou,
          sum( if( s.averageScore = s2.averageScore, 1, 0 )) as SameAverageAsYou,
          sum( if( s.averageScore > s2.averageScore, 1, 0 )) as HigherAverageThanYou
       from 
          scoreListing s
             join scoreListing s2
                ON s2.UserID = 95890 ) PreQuery,
```

You obviously have to wait until your machine gets freed-up to try again.

I would also have two indexes on the scoreListing table.  One on just the ID to jump to UserID = 95890 record for comparing that person's average, and another on the averageScore, so if you did HIGHER THAN only, your WHERE clause would only have to scan through those records and not the entire 400,000 records.

Comment: @MertMermi, revised and have SQLFiddle sample posted to show impact.  Even my original query worked on my machine.

Comment: sorry for late reply, a bit busy days. I just tried works fine. thanks a lot :) clever solution